# GNU Pattern Match and replace exact number of characters

Tags: linux, sed, regular-expression, wildcards, gnu

This question may have been listed but I was not able to find one exact hit.

I am trying to skim through a file, match a pattern and replace it with something else.
However there are other occurrences of the pattern but I need to replace only those which are 17 characters in length.

Example:

Content:

```
dlkfhfd|fedfe|dfwe3f347fde|3745978|dlkfhr**|376663781736102|**fedfe|dfwe3f347fde
```

Expectation:

```
dlkfhfd|fedfe|dfwe3f347fde|3745978|dlkfhr**|37xxxxxxxxxxxxx|**fedfe|dfwe3f347fde
```

Progress:
I was able to match the expression with regexp pattern : `**\|37[0-9]{13}\|**`

However if I put it in an `sed`, it just replaces everything in the file.

```
sed -e s/\|37[0-9]{13}\|/\|37xxxxxxxxxxxxx\|/g
```

My sed version is 4.2.2

Comment: Forgot to mention the file is pipe delimited.

Answer (score 7):

Your regular expression is a mix between basic and extended regular expression.

As an extended regular expression (using `{13}` and `\|` as a literal pipe):

```
sed -E 's/\|37[0-9]{13}\|/|37xxxxxxxxxxxxx|/g'
```

Alternatively, as a basic regular expression (using `\{13\}` and `|` as a literal pipe):

```
sed 's/|37[0-9]\{13\}|/|37xxxxxxxxxxxxx|/g'
```

This turns your example string into

```
dlkfhfd|fedfe|dfwe3f347fde|3745978|dlkfhr**|37xxxxxxxxxxxxx|**fedfe|dfwe3f347fde
```

Also note that there is no need to escape the `|` in the replacement part of the expression as that part is never interpreted as a regular expression.

---

In `awk`:

```
awk -F '|' -vOFS='|' '
    {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i))
            if (length($i)==15 && match($i,"^37[0-9]"))
                $i="37xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        print 
     }'
```

One could have used `gsub()` here, but that would have made it more or less identical to the `sed` solution, and therefore boring.

This has the benefit that the substitution would also occur in the first or last field even if that field was not delimited by `|` at both ends.

Comment: One question though, is there a specific version of SED which supports extended and regular both? Or it has to be either of them?

Comment: @Ishan I have tested the two `sed` commands with both GNU and BSD `sed`. Neither of these two `sed` implementations allow for mixing extended and basic regular expression syntax. Also, if they did, they would not know what to do with `|` and/or `\|`.